# Is it possible to POST values to next page with a Drupal URL?

Tags: uri

I have the following link that works if I link to an external page outside Drupal. However, when I place the same code in a Drupal page that is on orangeEDIT, and change this URL to point to the Drupal location, it says the page cannot be found.

```
<a href="http://host/drupal1/?q=node/17?orange_id=<?= $row['orange_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

I should probably use the Form API for this, as it is a link that allows a form to be edited, but it seems a way too complicated, compared to the PHP solution.

Comment: try this `<a href="http://localhost/globals/PGeditors/orangeEDIT.php?orange_id=<?=$row['orange_id'];?>`

Comment: I totally pasted the wrong url before. I meant to show the drupal one that doesn't work. So what im looking to do it post the id from one drupal page, to another, but when I do it this way, I get page cannot be found.

Comment: If you pasted the URL then `http://host/drupal1/?q=node/17?orange_id=<?=$row['orange_id'];?>` is not valid. `http://host/drupal1/?q=node/17&orange_id=<?=$row['orange_id'];?>` is valid. Or `http://host/drupal1/node/17?orange_id=<?=$row['orange_id'];?>`

Comment: Neither worked. The links stay within drupal, but it is like it thinks the whole thing is a URL, rather than part of it as info to load.

Comment: You forgot to say where you are using the link you show; since `$row['orange_id']` is not something Drupal makes available, knowing that could help in answering your question. Are you using it in a view, in a panel, or in something different?

Comment: Im taking this value form a page node, I can currently post that value to an external html/php page that brings up the relative record. However if I place the same code on that html/php code on a node within drupal, when I link to that drupal page, as I would with the hmtl/php code drupal doesn't like the URL.

Comment: You have to specify full url. Your href="something.php" is same as "drupal.com/something.php".

Comment: The URL however is a drupal node, If I use `http://host/drupal1/?q=node/17` that works but not when I add the get value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two ? characters and you are not actually printing the php variable. It should be like this:

```
<a href="http://host/drupal1/?q=node/17&orange_id=<?php print $row['orange_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Notice that because you have multiple query parameters (q & orange_id), that are to be separated by an ampersand (&).
Also, use the print function to print $row['orange_id'];

**Edit**

If you enable clean urls you could do this:

```
<a href="http://host/drupal1/node/17?orange_id=<?php print $row['orange_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

To prepare links in Drupal, use the [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
$options = array('query' => array('orange_id' => $row['orange_id']));
$link = l('Edit', 'node/17', $options);
```

You can also add `'absolute' => TRUE` to your options array to get the full URL; full options are on the docs page.

Using `l()` you can ensure that your URL is valid at all times.